# how to make disable the default leftbarbutton in navigation bar in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I want to disable the left bar button when my webview is loading can any one tell how to disable the leftbarbutton?

Anyone'shelp will be much appreciated.
Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`enabled` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007520-CH3-SW15) of the leftBarButtonItem to NO.

Comment: I tried like this but the button was not disabled yet.can u please giv any other suggestions?


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

Comment: @monish: Is that the left bar button item or the back bar button item (which is pentagonal) you want to disable?

Comment: @monish: You need to set `enabled` for the `backBarButtonItem` property. If this doesn't work then there's no AppStore-friendly way to disable that. (You can hide it with `-setHidesBackButton:animated:`, however.)

Comment: Yes I tried enabling the backBarButtonItem but its not working.only hidesBackBarItem is working.

Answer (score 1):

I put a blank image at the leftBarButtonItem to hide the back button on the first page.

```
 UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@""]; [btn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
btn.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,btnImage.size.width, btnImage.size.height);
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

This one line Code enough

**self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;**